# Other AJAX request waiting for Long Poll to finish

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, long-polling

I have a long-polling script that looks for changes in database. If data changes the while-loop will be exited and the data written to the user. The long poll "pushes" flight connections to the user. The user can then click on the connection and see the prices of the travel agents which come out of the MYSQL database again.

When the long poll is idle waiting for database changes and when at this time the user fires a second request to get the prices then the second AJAX request does not respond until the first AJAX request finishes.

I initially thought that Sessions are the problem and therefore I inserted session_write_close(); to the long poll script but that didn't resolve the issue! Can the community please help me with this issue? I don't want the user to keep waiting until the long poll finishes!!!

Server-side Long Polling:

```html
<?php

require( 'wp-load.php' );


$unique_id = isset($_GET['unique_id']) ? $_GET['unique_id'] : null;
$last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (float)$_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$last_price_update = isset($_GET['timestamp_price']) ? (float)$_GET['timestamp_price'] : 0;
global $sortType;
$sortType = isset($_GET['sortType']) ? $_GET['sortType'] : null;
global $wpdb;

function getData($unique_id, $last_ajax_call) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $sortType;
    
    if ($sortType == 'duration') {
        $sortString = "order by duration asc, cheapest_price asc";
    } else if ($sortType == 'price') {
        $sortString = "order by cheapest_price asc, duration asc;";
    } else {
        $sortString = "order by total_rating asc, cheapest_price asc;";
    }
    
    $data = Array();
    if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tl_connections_" . $unique_id . "'") == "tl_connections_" . $unique_id) {

        $query = "SELECT timestamp FROM tl_connections_" . $unique_id . " WHERE timestamp > " . $last_ajax_call . " order by timestamp desc limit 1;";
        $result = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_A);
        $data[1] = $result['timestamp'];
       
        
        $len = count($result);
        if ($len == 1) {
            $query = "SELECT content, timestamp FROM tl_connections_" . $unique_id . " WHERE timestamp > 1 " . $sortString;
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $data[0] = $data[0] . $row['content'];
                //$wpdb->query("UPDATE tl_connections_" . $unique_id . " SET timestamp = 1000000000 where id = " . $row['id'] . ";");
            }
        }
    }
    //$wpdb->close();
    return $data;
}

function getStatus($unique_id){
   global $wpdb;
   if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tl_status_".$unique_id."'") == "tl_status_".$unique_id) {
   $sql_status = "SELECT content FROM tl_status_".$unique_id." ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
   //echo $sql;
   $last_row_status = $wpdb->get_row($sql_status);
   $status = $last_row_status->content;
   //echo "Last changed: ".$last_change_in_data_file;
   }
   return $status;
}

define('MESSAGE_POLL_MICROSECONDS', 500000);
 
// How long to keep the Long Poll open, in seconds
define('MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS', 60);
 
// Timeout padding in seconds, to avoid a premature timeout in case the last call in the loop is taking a while
define('MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS_BUFFER', 5);

session_write_close();
 
// Automatically die after timeout (plus buffer)
set_time_limit(MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS+MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS_BUFFER);
 
// Counter to manually keep track of time elapsed (PHP's set_time_limit() is unrealiable while sleeping)
$counter = MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS;
 
// Poll for messages and hang if nothing is found, until the timeout is exhausted
while($counter > 0)
{
    // Check for new data
    $data = getData($unique_id, $last_ajax_call);
    
    if($data[0])
    {
        // Break out of while loop if new data is populated
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, sleep for the specified time, after which the loop runs again
        if (getStatus($unique_id)=="UpdatesComplete"){
            
          break;
        }
        $wpdb->close();
        usleep(MESSAGE_POLL_MICROSECONDS);
        $wpdb->check_connection();

        // Decrement seconds from counter (the interval was set in μs, see above)
        $counter -= MESSAGE_POLL_MICROSECONDS / 1000000;
        
    }
}
 
// If we've made it this far, we've either timed out or have some data to deliver to the client
if(isset($data[0]))
{
    // Send data to client; you may want to precede it by a mime type definition header, eg. in the case of JSON or XML
    $result = array(
            'data' => $data[0],
            'timestamp' => $data[1]);
        $json = json_encode($result);
        echo $json;
}
 
 else {
    $result = array(
            'data' => "End",
            'timestamp' => $data[1]);
        $json = json_encode($result);
        echo $json;
}
```

Client-Side Long Polling

```html
function getContent(timestamp, unique_id, direct_flight) {

    console.log('Start Long Polling');
    if (!jQuery('.offers_summary_detail_active').attr('data-type') === true) {
        var sortType = "best";
    } else {
        var sortType = jQuery('.offers_summary_detail_active').attr('data-type');
    }

    jQuery('#content_unique_id').prop('value', unique_id);
    jQuery('#content_direct_flight').prop('value', direct_flight);

    ContentRequest = jQuery.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.direktflug.de/tl_longpoll.php',
                data: {timestamp: timestamp, unique_id: unique_id, sortType: sortType},
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    //console.log(obj.data);

                        div_inner.innerHTML = obj.data;


                    getContent(obj.timestamp, unique_id, direct_flight);
                }
            });
}
```

Server-side of second AJAX request getting the prices

```html
<?php
require( 'wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;
$unique_id = $_POST["unique_id"];
$outbound_id = $_POST["outbound_id"];
$inbound_id = $_POST["inbound_id"];
$query = "SELECT content FROM tl_prices_".$unique_id." WHERE outbound_id='".$outbound_id."' AND inbound_id='".$inbound_id."' ORDER BY price ASC, binary(agent_name) desc";
//echo $query;
//exit;
$prices = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ( $prices as $price ) 
{
 echo $price->content;
}
```

Comment: I should maybe also mention that this whole thing runs on an NGINX server with Wordpress as CMS. session.auto_start is OFF.

Comment: It's usually better to update the question itself rather than making a comment.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should look into using Wordpress [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs.

Comment: It also might be worth looking into websockets. It allows you to pass data to the client directly via a socket and avoids polling (and also avoid the client connection limits)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, I will look into avoiding SQL injections with prepare(), however that won't solve the above mentioned issue.

Comment: No, but security should always be prio. 1 :-) You should look into web sockets, just as @apokryfos suggested.

Comment: Usually it happens when you have session_start() in your php. To escape session conflicts you might need session_write_close() function before time consuming operations.

Comment: @OlegLubimoff As you can see in the server-side Long polling script, I have included session_write_close() but it's still happening.